# Convert lambda to expression tree

Tags: c#, linq, expression-trees

Could someone please help me convert the below statement into a series of expression tree calls? I'm going nuts trying to get the select portion working.

```
results.GroupBy(x => x.EntityID).Select(y => y.OrderBy(o => o.ResultOrder).FirstOrDefault());
```

I tried debugging and looking at the expression in the inspector, but it made no sense to me whatsoever. I've got bits and pieces of it working, such as the groupby:

```
var groupAssign = Expression.Lambda<Func<TransViewModel, int>>(viewEntityIDProp, viewParam);
var grouped = Expression.Call(
    typeof (Queryable),
    "GroupBy",
    new Type[] { viewModelType, typeof(int) },
    new Expression[] { theBigResultset, groupAssign }
    );
```

Comment: What exactly didn't make sense to you?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve here, but one tool that always helped me for such things is [Linqpad](http://www.linqpad.net), which has a Dump extension method you can put on your expressions. You can declare lambdas like these as `Expression<Func<T, TResult>>`, then use the Dump method on the variable to obtain a readable expression tree that can later be used to perform the conversion. There might also be some free tools available but I'm unaware of these.
In your case most likely you have a:

```
Expression<Func<IEnumerable<TransViewModel>, IEnumerable<TransViewModel>>> stuff = results => results.GroupBy(x => x.EntityID).Select(y => y.OrderBy(o => o.ResultOrder).FirstOrDefault());
```

For which you can either call the Dump method and obtain the corresponding expression tree.

Comment: Thanks, but now I'm even more confused! Who'd have thought such a small line of code would end up generating so much gibberish! I'll have to look through a bit more closely.